# Can I develop .NET applications from virtual box on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualization

I have Ubuntu installed on my system. Now I have a project to do using Visual Studio in C#. I want to know whether I can install Windows inside a Virtual Box and then install Visual Studio. Will I be able to develop Csharp application in a virtual environment? Will the Virtual Box support the running of Visual Studio software? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You shouldn't have problems in developing in virtual environment. My friend uses ubuntu and virtual box to develop in Visual studio and he also uses VB to develop on OSX, i think(not sure about osx). He says that he had no problems. You may encounter problems if you're dealing with some complex graphics.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. Windows in virtualbox works very similar to how it works on a regular non virtual host. The only part that may be a bit troublesome is developing apps that use directx.